# You have an error in your SQL syntax, Check your MYSQL Version

Tags: php, mysql

Full Error:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.24]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 ID,category,Image1 FROM 3dprints WHERE category='model_making' ORDER' at line 1, SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect.

```
public function get_max_category($category){
    $query="SELECT TOP 1 ID,category,Image1
            FROM ".$this->tblname." WHERE category='".$category."'
            ORDER BY Date_of_creation DESC";
    $exec=odbc_exec($this->cnx,$query);
    $id=odbc_result($exec,'ID');
    $category=odbc_result($exec,'category');
    $img1=odbc_result($exec,'Image1');
    return array($id,$category,$img1);
}

public function get_category(){
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM ".$this->tblname;
    $exec=odbc_exec($this->cnx,$query); 
    while($row=odbc_fetch_row($exec)){
        $categories[]=odbc_result($exec,'category');
    }
    return $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `TOP 1` and add `LIMIT 1` end of query

Change following

```
$query="SELECT TOP 1 ID,category,Image1
            FROM ".$this->tblname." WHERE category='".$category."'
            ORDER BY Date_of_creation DESC";
```

TO

```
$query="SELECT ID,category,Image1
                FROM ".$this->tblname." WHERE category='".$category."'
                ORDER BY Date_of_creation DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: thanks it works. anyway i think my problem is i'm using the old syntax. thanks sadikhasan,